# Call a second method through AJAX with RAILS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, methods

I am trying to use ajax to call a method through my rails app.  I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve info via ajax whether that method when through successfully or call another fumction.

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET/POST", // which ever will be better 
  url: "",
  success: function(form) {
    //something i can put here to call a method in rails to retrieve variables from rails
  },
  error: function() {
    //some code
  }
});
```

What would I have to do to controller to get this to work ?

```
def call_sms
  @text_number = params[:phone_number]
  @text_message     = params[:text_message].to_s
  @sms = ShortMessagingService.new

  if @sms.send(@text_number, @text_message)       
    @sms_message = @sms.sent?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :nothing => true}
    end
  else 
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but generally speaking a nice way to handle Ajax requests in Rails is to send back JavaScript, which is executed on arrival. For example, if you change your controller to:

```
def call_sms
  @text_number = params[:phone_number]
  @text_message     = params[:text_message].to_s
  @sms = ShortMessagingService.new

  @sms.send(@text_number, @text_message)       

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and create a corresponding view call_sms.js.erb

```
<% if @sms.sent? %>
  alert("All is well!");
<% else %>
  alert("Something's wrong.");
<% end %>
```

an alert box will pop up once the response from server gets to your browser.

Alternatively, you can respond with a JSON object which you handle in the `success` callback of `$.ajax` function.

Comment: I just used this method just before i looked at this answer and it worked the way I needed to.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since message not being sent is a known error, I would handle it within the success block . You can pass a `json` object from the server to client and put variables in it.  Here I am sending a message that is `true` if the sms was successfully sent.

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET/POST", // which ever will be better 
  url: "",
  success: function(data) {
     if (data.message == "true"){
      //message sent
     } else{
      //message was not send 
     }
  },
  error: function() {
    // handle if ajax request fails for unknown reasons
  }
});

def call_sms
  @text_number = params[:phone_number]
  @text_message     = params[:text_message].to_s
  @sms = ShortMessagingService.new
  @sms.send(@text_number, @text_message)
  @sms_message = @sms.sent?

   respond_to do |format|
        # you can pass other variables the same way as message
        format.js {render :json => {:message => @sms_message}}
  end
end
```